# How to find specific link in a page via Similar string in bs4 python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there any way for found link that contains this example string `Top 100 Club Tracks Vol.1 2019.rar`

but maybe the link contains this type of string

`Top_100_Club_Tracks_Vol.1_2019.rar` (uppercase and _)

`top 100 club tracks vol.1 2019.rar` (lowercase and white space)

`top.100.club.tracks.vol1.2019.rar` ( lowercase and dote)

i just try this code and it cant just find links contains specific string :

```
mystr = Top 100 Club Tracks Vol.1 2019.rar

 links = soup_music.find('a', text=Title).findNext("div",{"class":"postContent"}).findAll('a', attrs={'href':re.compile(mystr)})
```

Comment: Share your website link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is in an `a` tag you can use * contains operator and pass a list of Or strings to `select`

```
soup.select('[href*="Top 100 Club Tracks Vol.1 2019.rar"],[href*="top 100 club tracks vol.1 2019.rar"]')
```

keep adding comma separated variations to select as shown above.